# reloadRowsAtIndexPaths works only the first time

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I basically want to change the text of the cell when a user taps on it. It’s the only cell in the section. `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` works when I first run the app, but it doesn’t after that. Here’s what I tried to do:

```
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 1)
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

I also print `indexPath` to see if it changes after the user taps on it. And the console reads:

`<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000000116> {length = 2, path = 1 - 0}`

My question is, how does `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` really work in updating specific rows of the table? I can’t get my head around this.

Comment: `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` basically calls cellForRowAtIndexPath for each row provided. You have to update the dataSource (maybe an array) with the appropriate data before calling this method, otherwise you won't see a change.

Comment: Not related but `beginUpdates/endUpdates` has no effect at all when reloading rows. It affects only multiple `insert/delete/move` operations.

Comment: @WolfgangSchreurs How do we update the dataSource?

Comment: @vadian Thanks for pointing that out. I see it makes no difference.

Comment: Let's say you have a webservice that loads some data. When you call the webservice, it returns an array with items. When you try to reload the cell, you first call the webservice again to reload the items and update the array used for displaying the items in your table view. Afterwards you could call reloadRowsAtIndexPaths to reload the data in the cell.